# How do you run a command at computer boot (win7)?

Tags: windows-7, boot, cmd.exe, login-screen

I wanted to run certain commands once the computer boots (at the log in screen). Would this be possible?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @techie007 That link doesn't seem to answer the question at all. He mentions the log-in screen for a reason, which makes me assume he wants it either pre-login or directly after the login happens.

Comment: Please be a little more clear in terms of do you want console of some sort BEFORE a user logs in... an admin console, maybe?  Or are you simply looking to run a command at boot time **WITHOUT** user intervention, in other words, **whether OR NOT the user is logged in**?

Comment: for good or evil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this in fact. The only thing I'm unsure of is what you mean by "at the login screen". Do you mean, directly after you logged in, or while no user is logged in?

Given that there is one method that allows both and only needs one small change in the execution, I'll use that method. If you want as soon as the user logs in, but way before the desktop is shown, there are other options too.

## Using the Task Scheduler

1. Start the `Task Scheduler` (located in Control Panel->Administrative Tools)
2. Create a `new basic task`. (you can also use the create a new task option, but lets keep it simple for now.)
3. Give it a `name` and `description`, hit <kbd>next ></kbd>.
4. As Trigger either choose `When the computer starts` (pre-logon) or `When I log on` (post-logon) and hit <kbd>next ></kbd>.
5. As action, choose `Start a program` and hit <kbd>next ></kbd>
6. Browse to the program. If your program or script requires additional arguments, fill them all in the Add arguments location. For example: net use z: \myserver\share would become Program:net; arguments: use z: \myserver\share
7. Fill in Start in if this is required, otherwise leave blank, and hit <kbd>Next ></kbd>.
8. You can <kbd>Finish</kbd> here, or check the `Open the properties dialog for this task when I click Finish` button to edit the task with advanced options. (this would give you the same dialog as if you clicked New task.

And there you have it. Next time you reboot your computer, this task will run.

## Testing if it works

Now obviously you could reboot and see if it works, but lets first test the task right now. Right click the newly created task and choose `run`. The task will run and you can see if works as expected.

Note that running a task pre-logon, will run the task as a user that does not interact with the desktop, so you can't see any visual clues on the desktop about the task.

## Note:

Running a task using task scheduler post-login, will not run the task as soon as you click next, but it will run it fast. If you need it to run directly after you click next, you'll need to use a login script which you can use with a policy or on a domain from the domain controller. Given that you seldomly need to run a program directly post-login, I did not write how to do it here. Your question was not specific enough if this is what you're after.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much for the help! I tried that before but put the whole command and arguments in the Program parameter.